# Variable from another class

Tags: ios, swift, class

I have a problem when accessing the variable from another class.

I am initializing and modifying variable here

**TheResponse Class**

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire

class TheResponse {

typealias JSONStd = [[String : AnyObject]]
var jsonAnswer = [[String:String]]()

var getRes: [[String : String]] {
    return jsonAnswer
}

func callAmo(){
    let urladdress = "https://api.github.com/users"
    Alamofire.request(urladdress).responseJSON(completionHandler: {
        response in
        //print(response)
        self.parseData(JSONData: response.data!)
    })
}

func parseData(JSONData : Data){

    do {
        var readableJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: JSONData, options: .mutableContainers) as! JSONStd
            let counter = readableJSON.count
 //Filling the dictionary
        for item in 0...counter - 1 {
            let login = readableJSON[item]["login"]
            let avatar_url = readableJSON[item]["avatar_url"]
            let html_url = readableJSON[item]["html_url"]
            let id = String(describing: readableJSON[item]["id"])

            var dict:[String:AnyObject] = ["login": login!,
                        "avatar": avatar_url!,
                        "profile": html_url!,
                        "id": id as AnyObject]

            jsonAnswer.append(dict as! [String : String])
        }
    }
    catch{
        print(error)
    }
}
}
```

If I will print somewhere here the jsonAnswer variable, everything looks fine. 
But I want to use this variable in my second class

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
var resObj = TheResponse()
var jsonData = [[String:String]]()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    resObj.callAmo{ (jsonAns) -> () in
        self.jsonData = jsonAns
       // print(self.jsonData)
    }
    print(self.jsonData)

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 5
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCell", for: indexPath) as! MainViewCell

    return cell
}

}
```

The problem is that when I want to print the variable in `TableViewController` class, the variable is empty. As print out I am getting only [].

How should I access the variable to have it as it should be?

Comment: Your code seems to do what you wrote? you call `resObj.getRes` which return `jsonAnswer  = [[String:String]]()` which is empty, nothing wrong?

Comment: In pareJson method I am filling the jsonAnswer with 

`jsonAnswer.append(dict as! [String : String])`

Comment: Yes but you never called that function, and what you putting is quite wrong, you have to create completion block on `callAmo()` , not use the array as a stored property

Comment: So you mean, that everything what is in `parseJSON()` should be done in `callAmo() `?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you haven't call `callAmo` method also, you need to create completion closure with your method, so change your code like this.

```
func callAmo(completion: ([[String : String]]) -> ()) {
    let urladdress = "https://api.github.com/users"
    Alamofire.request(urladdress).responseJSON(completionHandler: {
        response in
        //print(response)
        let dic = self.parseData(JSONData: response.data!)
        completion(dic)
    })
}
```

Now return the dictionary from `parseData` methods like this.

```
func parseData(JSONData : Data) -> [[String: String]]{

    do {
        var readableJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: JSONData, options: .mutableContainers) as! JSONStd
        let counter = readableJSON.count
         //Filling the dictionary
        for item in 0...counter - 1 {
            let login = readableJSON[item]["login"]
            let avatar_url = readableJSON[item]["avatar_url"]
            let html_url = readableJSON[item]["html_url"]
            let id = String(describing: readableJSON[item]["id"])

            var dict:[String:AnyObject] = ["login": login!,
                    "avatar": avatar_url!,
                    "profile": html_url!,
                    "id": id as AnyObject]

            jsonAnswer.append(dict as! [String : String])
        } 
    }
    catch{
        print(error)
    }
    return jsonAnswer
}
```

Now call this method in `viewDidLoad` of `TableViewController` like this.

```
resObj.callAmo{ (jsonAns) -> () in
    print(jsonAns)
}
```

**Edit:** To get the data in `TableViewController` do like this

```
var jsonData = [[Strin:String]]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    resObj.callAmo{ (jsonAns) -> () in
        self.jsonData = jsonAns
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.jsonData.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCell", for: indexPath) as! MainViewCell
    return cell
}
```

Comment: But one more question.
If I want to have a copy of `jsonAns` in `TableViewController`, can I just make `resObj.callAmo{ (jsonAns) -> () in
    let copy = jsonAns
} ` ?

Comment: Yes you can but that will not available outside the closure block so better to declare one instance at class level and use that inside closure,

Comment: Okay, 
So I've declared it like below, to have available inside the class 
`class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var resObj = TheResponse()
    var jsonData = [[String:String]]()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        resObj.callAmo{ (jsonAns) -> () in
            self.jsonData = jsonAns
        }
        print(jsonData)
        
    }......`

But again `jsonData` is empty :/ 
Is I didn't understand you correctly?

Comment: Try to add this code in question also have you try to print jsonAns, check is it empty array?

Comment: I tried to print jsonAns inside the closure, works fine , 
then I've tried to print jsonData inside closure, works fine,  
but outside the closure jsonData is empty, however is declared as I mentioned. I will edit everything in question

Comment: The problem is closure will execute later, if you want to populate this array on json, after setting jsonData with jsonAns in closure just reload the tableView with in that closure.

Comment: I will just explain what I want to achieve. 
At this moment everything looks fine, as I can print the content of JSON in my table view.
I am using the closure in drawing cell. 
But before I would like to know the size of JSON, how many entries is there, to prepare tableView so it will be better to have copy of this JSON inside the class, that I can use wherever I want.

Comment: Check the edited answer and do like this, because if your closure is execute async where as your print that is outside closure execute first.

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for. 
You are the man!!!!! Thanks :)